# How can a make an animation like a moving arrow for an image

Tags: flash-cs3

i want to show the flow of the air that goes something like circle.. how can i make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of using flash just use gimp or photoshop.. its easier there.. frame by frame..